# How can I make multi language config in Nginx?

Tags: redirect, nginx, multilingual, proxypass

I have following Nginx config `default.conf`:

```
map $http_accept_language $browser_lang {
        default en;
        ~ru ru;
}
map $cookie_lang $lang {
    default $browser_lang;
    ~en en;
    ~ru ru;
}

server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;

    #charset koi8-r;
    #access_log  /var/log/nginx/log/host.access.log  main;

    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;

        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

    #error_page  404              /404.html;

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
}
```

How can I do following:

1) Pass all `/*` requests to `/en/*` or `/ru/*` depending of language?

2) Pass all `/en/*` to `/usr/share/nginx/html/<request>?lang=en` and `/ru/*` to `/usr/share/nginx/html/<request>?lang=ru`?

3) If language is not `en` and `ru` path to all `/*` requests to `/en/*`?

Answer (score 2):

You need to apply two separate `location` blocks for root url and for your language sections like so:

```
location = / {
    rewrite ^ $scheme://$host/$lang$uri$is_args$args break;
}

location ~ '^/(?<lang_code>[\w-]{2})' {
    rewrite ^/(?<lang_code>[\w-]{2})/(.*)$ /$1?lang=$lang_code last;

    ...
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index  index.html index.htm;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    ...
}
```

First `location` block answers to you questions 1) and 3) where the root url will be rewritten with your `$lang` variable in it that comes from `map` section and the last one defines that you will be using `en` language as default.

Second `location` block is for your questions 2) where you accept your language param as two-char path and then rewrite your url to suit your needs.

This code may not be 100% working, but it should give you an idea.

**UPDATE**

Well, actually you can do this in one single pass:

```
location / {
    if ($uri !~ '^/([a-z]{2})(/.*)?$') {
        rewrite ^ $scheme://$host/$lang$uri permanent;
        rewrite ^/([a-z]{2})(/.*)?$ /$2?lang=$1;
    }
    ...
}
```